# Turning a Pandas Dataframe to an array and evaluate Multiple Linear Regression Model

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to evaluate a multiple linear regression model. I have a data set like this :

[image]

This data set has 157 rows * 54 columns.

I need to predict ground_truth value from articles. I will add my multiple linear model 7 articles between **en_Amantadine** with **en_Common**.

I have code for multiple linear regression :

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = [[6, 2], [8, 1], [10, 0], [14, 2], [18, 0]] // need to modify for my problem
y = [[7],[9],[13],[17.5], [18]] // need to modify
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
```

My problem is, I cannot extract data from my DataFrame for **X** and **y** variables. In my code X should be:

```
X = [[4984, 94, 2837, 857, 356, 1678, 29901],
     [4428, 101, 4245, 906, 477, 2313, 34176],
      ....
     ]
y = [[3.135999], [2.53356] ....]
```

I cannot convert DataFrame to this type of structure. 
How can i do this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn the dataframe into a matrix using the method `as_matrix` directly on the dataframe object. You might need to specify the columns which you are interested in `X=df[['x1','x2','X3']].as_matrix()` where the different x's are the column names.

For the y variables you can use `y = df['ground_truth'].values` to get an array.

Here is an example with some randomly generated data:

```
import numpy as np
#create a 5X5 dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0, 100, (5, 5)), columns = ['X1','X2','X3','X4','y'])
```

calling `as_matrix()` on `df` returns a `numpy.ndarray` object

```
X = df[['X1','X2','X3','X4']].as_matrix()
```

Calling `values` returns a `numpy.ndarray` from a pandas `series`

```
y =df['y'].values
```

Notice: You might get a warning saying:`FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.`

To fix it use `values` instead of `as_matrix` as shown below

```
X = df[['X1','X2','X3','X4']].values
```

Comment: I editted my question, it seems there is a problem. Could please help on this ?

Comment: If you want to get only one column and you know the column. You can use it like this -> `Y = df['column_name'].as_matrix()`

Comment: As of pandas 0.23, as_matrix() has been deprecated, and values should work both on Series and DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = broken_df.ground_truth.values
X = broken_df.drop('ground_truth', axis=1).values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
print(linreg.score(X_test, y_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: there is no reference to a `DataFrame` in your answer.