# Position variances and covariances in matrix form

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy

We have the following sets of data which are already given to us : `A,B,C` that represent variances and `D,E, F` that represent covariances . I would like to position this sets of data in the matrix form:

```
 matrix:   Z     Y     X
        Z  A     D     F
        Y  D     B     E
        X  F     E     C
```

How can I arrange the sets of data in the matrix form considering that I don't Know the number of variances/cov?

Then I would like the resulting matrix multiply :

```
 matrix*  (G,H,I) * (G
                     H
                     I)
```

The second question is , how I multiply matrix `dimensions 3*3 by 1*3 and 3*1

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry , just edited the question

Comment: The second question is just [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.matrix` and `numpy.array` to create your own matrix and arrays,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

        matrix1 = np.matrix([[1, 4, 6], [4, 2, 5],[6, 5, 3]])

        array1 = np.array([7,8,9])
```

Second question: Now use `numpy.transpose` to calculate the quadratic matrix from array1,

```
In [2]: matrix2 = array1*np.transpose([array1])

In [3]: matrix2

Out[3]: array([[49, 56, 63],
               [56, 64, 72],
               [63, 72, 81]])
```

Finally, multiply both matrix with `numpy.matmul`,

```
In [4]: matrix3 = np.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)

In [5]: matrix3

Out[5]: matrix([[651, 744, 837],
                [623, 712, 801],
                [763, 872, 981]])
```

Comment: Thank You very much Manel , it was a great explanation, however in this case I really need to work with the results of the example

Comment: @ge00rge What's the problem? The covariances and variances are numeric values , isn't it?

Comment: Yes that is correct , however lets say that the cov is not obtained as usual and for this case firstly the results are obtained and then the matrix is built with those results

Comment: @ge00rge Of course, you want to convert your DataFrame into a matrix from, isn't?

Comment: Yes, sorry Manel .

Comment: @ge00rge don't apologize, i didn't see. Well, you should read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334091/turning-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-array-and-evaluate-multiple-linear-regression-m) I think that is helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142829/discussion-between-manel-fornos-and-ge00rge).