# convert pandas df to multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have very sparse data in a pandas dataframe with 25million+ records.  This has to be converted into a multi dimensional numpy array.  I have written this the straightforward way using a `for` loop, and was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

facts_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_records(columns=['name','offset','code'],
    data=[('John', -928, 'dx_434'), ('Steve',-757,'dx_5859'), ('Jack',-800,'dx_250'),
          ('John',-919,'dx_401'),('John',-956,'dx_5859')])

name_lu = pd.DataFrame(sorted(facts_pd['name'].unique()), columns=['name'])
name_lu["nameid"] = name_lu.index

offset_lu = pd.DataFrame(sorted(facts_pd['offset'].unique(), reverse=True), columns=['offset'])
offset_lu["offsetid"] = offset_lu.index

code_lu = pd.DataFrame(sorted(facts_pd['code'].unique()), columns=['code'])
code_lu["codeid"] = code_lu.index

facts_pd = pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(facts_pd, name_lu, how="left", on="name")
    , offset_lu, how="left", on="offset"), code_lu, how="left", on="code")
facts_pd.drop(["name","offset","code"], inplace=True, axis=1)

facts_np = np.zeros((len(name_lu),len(offset_lu),len(code_lu)))
for row in facts_pd.iterrows():
    i,j,k = row[1]
    facts_np[i][j][k] = 1
```

Comment: I believe there should be a quick way using `.values` and `.reshape`. Can you please indicate what your input looks like, and how you want it transformed, for some toy data?

Comment: my input looks like `facts_pd` and I would like to output like `facts_np`

Comment: Thanks, but I was referring to actual data values, or toy samples. It isn't clear what is in `row[1]` and how you want it to translate.

Comment: Generally it is better to index an array with `facts_np[i, j, k]`.  In fact you might be able use `facts_np[row[1]]` or `facts_np[tuple(row[1])]`.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are probably looking for is `dataframe.as_matrix()` this will return a numpy array and not a matrix despite what the command says [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) is the man pages for it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334091/turning-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-array-and-evaluate-multiple-linear-regression-m) is another stack overflow topic on the use of it as well

Answer (score -1):

Refurbished code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

facts_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_records(columns=['name','offset','code'],
    data=[('John', -928, 'dx_434'), ('Steve',-757,'dx_5859'), ('Jack',-800,'dx_250'),
          ('John',-919,'dx_401'),('John',-956,'dx_5859')])

facts_np = facts_pd.as_matrix()

print facts_np # Displays the data frame in numpy array format.
```