# multioutput classifier/learning 5 target variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, multilabel-classification

I am a newbie to machine learning. I have been struggling with a problem for a few weeks now and I hope someone can help here:

I have a data set with one continuous variable and the rest are categorical. I managed to encode the categorical variables and would like to build a multi output classifier.

Here is my data set:
[Snapshot of my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIGyb.png)
I have these features : A, B
I would like to predict : C,D,E,F, G

The data set looks like this: A,B,C,D,E,F,G

I spent days on the documentation on multi-output classifiers on the scikitlearn and here but none of the documentation seems clear to me.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to find some sample code on how to create the classifier and predict with some sample data?

Thank you in advance
P.S: I am not using TensorFlow and would appreciate your help for sklearn.

Answer (score 12):

This is called [multi-task learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-task_learning), which basically means a model that learns several functions, but shares (some or all) weights. It's fairly common, for example one model for image recognition and detection. What you need to do is to define several loss functions (they are called *heads*).

Here's a very simple example in tensorflow that learns `Y1` and `Y2` from `X` (from [this post series](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/07/multi-task-learning-tensorflow-part-1.html)):

```
# Define the Placeholders
X = tf.placeholder("float", [10, 10], name="X")
Y1 = tf.placeholder("float", [10, 1], name="Y1")
Y2 = tf.placeholder("float", [10, 1], name="Y2")

# Define the weights for the layers
shared_layer_weights = tf.Variable([10,20], name="share_W")
Y1_layer_weights = tf.Variable([20,1], name="share_Y1")
Y2_layer_weights = tf.Variable([20,1], name="share_Y2")

# Construct the Layers with RELU Activations
shared_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X,shared_layer_weights))
Y1_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(shared_layer,Y1_layer_weights))
Y2_layer_weights = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(shared_layer,Y2_layer_weights))

# Calculate Loss
Y1_Loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(Y1,Y1_layer)
Y2_Loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(Y2,Y2_layer)
```

If you wish to code in pure scikit, see [`sklearn.multiclass`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) package, they support multioutput classification and multioutput regression. Here's an example of multioutput regression:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
>>> from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
>>> X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10, n_targets=3, random_state=1)
>>> MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)).fit(X, y).predict(X)
array([[-154.75474165, -147.03498585,  -50.03812219],
       [   7.12165031,    5.12914884,  -81.46081961],
       [-187.8948621 , -100.44373091,   13.88978285],
       [-141.62745778,   95.02891072, -191.48204257],
       [  97.03260883,  165.34867495,  139.52003279],
       [ 123.92529176,   21.25719016,   -7.84253   ],
       [-122.25193977,  -85.16443186, -107.12274212],
       [ -30.170388  ,  -94.80956739,   12.16979946],
       [ 140.72667194,  176.50941682,  -17.50447799],
       [ 149.37967282,  -81.15699552,   -5.72850319]])
```

**[Update]**

Here's a *complete* code that does multi-target classification. Try to run it:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

# The data from your screenshot
#  A      B   C    D    E   F    G
train_data = np.array([
  [5, 133.5, 27, 284, 638, 31, 220],
  [5, 111.9, 27, 285, 702, 36, 230],
  [5,  99.3, 25, 310, 713, 39, 227],
  [5, 102.5, 25, 311, 670, 34, 218],
  [5, 114.8, 25, 312, 685, 34, 222],
])
# These I just made up
test_data_x = np.array([
  [5, 100.0],
  [5, 105.2],
  [5, 102.7],
  [5, 103.5],
  [5, 120.3],
  [5, 132.5],
  [5, 152.5],
])

x = train_data[:, :2]
y = train_data[:, 2:]
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=1)
classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(forest, n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(x, y)
print classifier.predict(test_data_x)
```

Output (well, looks reasonable to me):

```
[[  25.  310.  713.   39.  227.]
 [  25.  311.  670.   34.  218.]
 [  25.  311.  670.   34.  218.]
 [  25.  311.  670.   34.  218.]
 [  25.  312.  685.   34.  222.]
 [  27.  284.  638.   31.  220.]
 [  27.  284.  638.   31.  220.]]
```

If for some reason this doesn't work or can't be applied in your case, please update the question.

Comment: Hi Maxim, thanks for your answer. I looked at the example with sklearn.multiclass and as you can see, it looks to me that the examples are based on some artificially generated data, numpy arrays mostly. I struggle to specify the training and test sets from my own dataset.

Comment: @PatMuk is your data numerical or categorical? Numerical features can be read into numpy arrays, and categorical features can be encoded - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Comment: both. I already encoded all categorical variables. How do I split my data set from training to test sets? at this line: X, y1 = make_classification(n_samples=10, n_features=100, n_informative=30, n_classes=3, random_state=1), how does the code relate to my data set? sorry this seems trivial to you but it is giving me such a hard time.

Comment: Use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). Also you didn't provide any details about your data, so it's impossible to tell how to prepare the data.

Comment: The data is already prepared, I can do some prediction on a single target but I am stuck with predicting multiple targets as I explained. I attached a snapshot of my dataset. I appreciate your help!

Comment: so basically you also have no idea how to learn more than one targets? you just provided generic multi-label documentation (I already looked at).

Comment: @PatMuk Apologies for the delay, I've updated the answer. Try to be more polite next time.

Comment: apologies for the way my comment came out, if anything, you deserve gratitude. So thank you for being the only one who cared to share your knowledge. I am still working on the problem and hopefully I will figure it out. Your solution does not seem to work. I have  a dataframe, you have an array, (this is probably not a big issue but for a newbie like myself trying to understand the cause of every error is quite a challenge), probably I would have to look at parameters and tune them etc. In any case, Thanks for your effort!

Comment: No problem. Take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/28334091/712995